# Perfect squares in a XOR-Sum of perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let $x_0 = 0$ and $x_n = n^2 \oplus x_{n - 1}$ for $n \ge 2$, where $a \oplus b$ denotes the bitwise exclusive OR operation (XOR).

**QUESTION.** Are there infinitely many perfect squares in the sequence $(x_n)$?

I present my ideas and research as following. The first 50 numbers are: 0, 1, 5, 12, 28, 5, 33, 16, 80, 1, 101, 28, 140, 37, 225, 0, 256, 33, 357, 12, 412, 37, 449, 976, 400, 993, 325, 924, 140, 965, 65, 896, 1920, 961, 1861, 908, 1692, 965, 1633, 912, 1488, 833, 1445, 668, 1292, 741, 2721, 512, 2816, 609. Because I don't see a simple pattern, I limited the search to perfect squares. Considering the 100,000 numbers we get:

(1, 1), (7, 16), (9, 1), (14, 225), (15, 0), (16, 256), (24, 400), (33, 961), (63, 256), (89, 2401), (193, 4225), (240, 50176), (255, 9216), (271, 9216), (430, 113569), (448, 20736), (528, 518400), (575, 160000), (729, 893025), (742, 390625), (783, 861184), (903, 685584), (1297, 134689), (1776, 861184), (2409, 3568321), (2623, 389376), (3494, 6806881), (4079, 12730624), (4159, 12730624), (5439, 4260096), (8278, 105534529), (13631, 1081600), (13737, 297025), (16128, 153363456), (41825, 159744321), (53007, 3226240000), (64344, 666259344), (95985, 228584161), (99015, 1296)

Note that $x_a = b$ for each pair $(a, b)$, so $a$ denotes the index.
Increasing the search space yields a longer list, but it seems to grow sublinear.

If there are infinitely many zeros in the sequence, the claim follows. But in the first 1,000,000 numbers I found only one zero at index 15.

I assume there are infinitely many perfect squares in the sequence. Is that true? How to prove it?

**BONUS QUESTION.** Is there an $i \notin \{ 0, 15 \}$ with $x_i = 15$? If not, why?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A145768

Comment: Thanks, but the question asked there is different from my question. I don't care about specific numbers appearing a finite number of times. I'm only interested in perfect squares.

Comment: Sure, I was just showing that the sequence is in the OEIS to anyone reading this.  the first question to think about in my mind is what do squares look like in binary.

Comment: in fact with a little bit of work ( admittedly that I like a compute algebra system do), you can show, that they can't be at indexes, that have remainder 2 or 5 when dividing by 8.

Comment: Can you give the idea or a link? It's not obvious to me.

Comment: Use the fact, that squares have remainders of 0, 1, or 4  when dividing by 8 ( aka there last three bits will be 000,001, or 100) then try Xoring them in order and see what happens .